# Get contact name and family name from Android contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts, device

I'm building an app that needs to pick a contact from Android contacts. I do it and I use the following code in my app for retrieve name and family name form chosen contact (in `onActivityResult`).

```
Cursor namesc = getContentResolver().query( ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id,null, null);
if (namesc.moveToFirst()) {
String name = namesc.getString(namesc.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
String family = namesc.getString(namesc
.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
String middle = namesc.getString(namesc
.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME));
```

It works well in HTC phones and some other phones but in many of SE Xperia models and some Samsung devices it can't give me name and family and returns null. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use:

```
        String structuredNameWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?"; 
        String[] structuredNameWhereParams = new String[]{id, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}; 
        cursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, structuredNameWhere, structuredNameWhereParams, null); 
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
        { 
            String StructuredNameId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName._ID));
            String prefix = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.PREFIX));
            String givenName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
            String middleName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME));
            String familyName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
            String suffix = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.SUFFIX));
        }
```

The only difference I really see is I added mime-type to the where parameters and I am retrieving data slightly differently.

Answer (score 0):

[Android Contacts has just been REBORN](https://proandroiddev.com/android-contacts-reborn-19985c73ad43)! Using the [Contacts, Reborn API](https://github.com/vestrel00/contacts-android), the answer to the original question,

> I use the following code in my app for retrieve name and family name form chosen contact... it can't give me name and family and returns null. Can anybody help me?

is the following...

In Java,

```java
public void printContactFullName(Context context, Long contactId) {
    Contacts contactsApi = ContactsFactory.create(context);
    Contact contact = contactsApi
            .query()
            .include(Fields.Name.getAll())
            .where(WhereKt.equalTo(Fields.Contact.Id, contactId))
            .find()
            .get(0);

    // Assuming this contact only have 1 RawContact...
    Name name = ContactDataKt.nameList(contact).get(0);
    Log.d(
            "Contact",
            "Prefix: " + name.getPrefix() +
            ", Given name: " + name.getGivenName() +
            ", Middle name: " + name.getMiddleName() +
            ", Family name: " + name.getFamilyName() +
            ", Suffix: " + name.getSuffix()
    );
}
```

In Kotlin,

```kotlin
fun printContactFullName(context: Context, contactId: Long) {
    Contacts(context)
        .query()
        .include(Fields.Name.all)
        .where(Fields.Contact.Id equalTo contactId)
        .find()
        .first().let { contact ->
            // Assuming this contact only have 1 RawContact...
            val name = contact.names().first()
            Log.d(
                "Contact",
                """
                    Prefix: ${name.prefix}
                    Given name: ${name.givenName}
                    Middle name: ${name.middleName}
                    Family name: ${name.familyName}
                    Suffix: ${name.suffix}
                """.trimIndent()
            )
        }
}
```

Do keep in mind, however, that not all Contacts have to have proper names. Users can create contacts without a name. This is the behavior in the native Contacts app.

You can do a lot more than this using the [Contacts, Reborn API](https://github.com/vestrel00/contacts-android). You can even build your own full-fledged Contacts application that can stand toe-to-toe with the one that comes with almost every copy of Android.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Return all contacts and show each contact data in android monitor    console as debug info. */    private List<ContactDTO> getAllContacts()    {
       List<ContactDTO> ret = new ArrayList<ContactDTO>();
       // Get all raw contacts id list.
       List<Integer> rawContactsIdList = getRawContactsIdList();
       int contactListSize = rawContactsIdList.size();
       ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
       // Loop in the raw contacts list.
       for(int i=0;i<contactListSize;i++)
       {
           // Get the raw contact id.
           Integer rawContactId = rawContactsIdList.get(i);
           Log.d(TAG_ANDROID_CONTACTS, "raw contact id : " + rawContactId.intValue());
           // Data content uri (access data table. )
           Uri dataContentUri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
           // Build query columns name array.
           List<String> queryColumnList = new ArrayList<String>();
           // ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID = "contact_id";
           queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID);
           // ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE = "mimetype";
           queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE);
           queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1);
           queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2);
           queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3);
           queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA4);
           queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA5);
           queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA6);
           queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA7);
           queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA8);
           queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA9);
           queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA10);
           queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA11);
           queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA12);
           queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA13);
           queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA14);
           queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA15);
           // Translate column name list to array.
           String queryColumnArr[] = queryColumnList.toArray(new String[queryColumnList.size()]);
           // Build query condition string. Query rows by contact id.
           StringBuffer whereClauseBuf = new StringBuffer();
           whereClauseBuf.append(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID);
           whereClauseBuf.append("=");
           whereClauseBuf.append(rawContactId);
           // Query data table and return related contact data.
           Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(dataContentUri, queryColumnArr, whereClauseBuf.toString(), null, null);
           /* If this cursor return database table row data.
              If do not check cursor.getCount() then it will throw error
              android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0.
              */
           if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount() > 0)
           {
               StringBuffer lineBuf = new StringBuffer();
               cursor.moveToFirst();
               lineBuf.append("Raw Contact Id : ");
               lineBuf.append(rawContactId);
               long contactId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID));
               lineBuf.append(" , Contact Id : ");
               lineBuf.append(contactId);
               do{
                   // First get mimetype column value.
                   String mimeType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE));
                   lineBuf.append(" \r\n , MimeType : ");
                   lineBuf.append(mimeType);
                   List<String> dataValueList = getColumnValueByMimetype(cursor, mimeType);
                   int dataValueListSize = dataValueList.size();
                   for(int j=0;j < dataValueListSize;j++)
                   {
                       String dataValue = dataValueList.get(j);
                       lineBuf.append(" , ");
                       lineBuf.append(dataValue);
                   }
               }while(cursor.moveToNext());
               Log.d(TAG_ANDROID_CONTACTS, lineBuf.toString());
           }
           Log.d(TAG_ANDROID_CONTACTS, "=========================================================================");
       }
       return ret;    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).